# Best approach to generate DDL for a table stored in Amazon S3 and load it into Amazon Redshift?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I need to backup few tables from Redshift to S3 (parquet preferred but not mandatory)
but the problem is I am not able to find out a way to store table DDL along with data.

Ultimately, I should be able to restore the backed-up tables from S3 to Redshift whenever required.

I am relatively new to the field, any expert advice or examples from those experienced in Redshift backup and restore processes would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried this Python library https://pypi.org/project/redshift-auto-schema/
but didn't get the correct column data types. I believe this library relies on regex or some other guessing methods.

Comment: I looked into "SHOW TABLE table_name" command
Can't I store this DDL in some text file in same path on S3 and then read this text file in my python script and run this query before copying data back to redshift?

Comment: Are you using UNLOAD to load table data to s3. If so then there is MANIFEST
 VERBOSE option that alongside creates file with table schema, you can check if that's what you need

Answer (score 0):

Use a glue crawler if you no longer have the original definition. Or do “show table” and store the result in a table, then unload that table to s3. U may have to use a proc and execute command to get show table output into a new temp table.